Apache 2.4 can't serve static content from Apache Web Server
I configured Apache web server and Tomcat.And ı have static folder that contain with in Tomcat webapps folder.The css file that in static folder changes my webpage login screen color.
When ı try to reach with localhost my login screen color changes as expected.But when ı try to connect with domain that ı declared in Apache Web Server it won't change.And returns following error;

https://test.webpage.com/static/login.css net::ERR_ABORTED 400

Here is my > httpd.vhost.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.webpage.com
    ServerAlias www.test.webpage.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-access.log" common

    <Directory "C:/Test/test2/AppServer/webapps/static/">
        Options +Indexes  
    AllowOverride None  
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  

    JkMount  /static/* prod
    JkMount  /static prod

</VirtualHost>

Example with localhost connection
Example with domain connection
What am I missing here?
Thank you.
I try to access Tomcat webapps static folder when ı try to connect with domain connection.But it not accessible.

Apparently your VirtualHost on port 443 does not contain any instructions required for SSL/TLS, e.g. key, certificate etc.
This means you're speaking http on a port that the browser assumes speaking https. You can validate this by going to http://your.example.com:443/login.css and it should load.
